# Sort an array of arrays in Erlang

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting, erlang

I need to sort arrays but not classical ones. Moreover, in Erlang !
I'm talking about arrays where each element is an array of two integers.

For example : 
[ [6,0], [12,1], [5,2], [10,3] ]

I need this array to be sorted in function of the first element of each arrays
Like this :

[ [5,2], [6,0], [10,3], [12,1] ]

First, I succeed with this :

```
-module(insertSort).
-export([insertion/1,insert/1,insert/2]).

insertion(L) -> lists:foldl(fun insert/2, [], L).

insert([]) -> [].

insert(X,[]) -> [X];
insert([],Y) -> [Y];

insert(X= [X1,_], L= [[H1,_] | _]) when X1 =< H1 -> [X|L];

insert(X,[H|T]) -> [H|insert(X, T)].
```

Sometimes, arrays are sorted. But I have two examples that gives me two weird cases:

**First :**
[ [10,3], [5,2], [12,1], [6,0] ]
become :
[[[5,2], [6,0], [10,3], [12,1]]]]

Not bad but I can't work with that weird construction. It seems that I have an array, where there is an array inside, where there is all my two-elements arrays inside.

**Second :** 
[ [5,16], [11,12], [9,8], [16,4] ]
become :
[[[5,16], "\t\b","\v\f",[16,4]]]

Yes, really, with these \t\b..

I'm a beginner in Erlang but I succeed to do a lot of things by myself.
My project is about Shank Algorithm, trying to solve *y = a^x mod n* where y, a and n are given.

Can you please help me by telling me what is wrong with my insertSort module ?

Thanks a lot, sorry for my english, I tried to do my best.

Comment: Note that "\t\b" is just another way of writing [9,8]. They mean exactly the same thing. Similarly, "\v\f" is the same as [11,12]. It's just that the shell will print it as a string if the list consists of printable character codes.

Comment: Thank you @RichardC for that enlightenment !

Comment: I cannot try it on my pad, but I think that `lists:sort(L).` does what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in my comment, the sort function of the lists library does exactly what you want.

```
1> lists:sort( [ [6,0], [12,1], [5,2], [10,3] ]).
[[5,2],[6,0],[10,3],[12,1]]
2>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think problem is with line:

```
insert([],Y) -> [Y];
```

Y is already a sorted list so it should be returned as it is

```
insert([],Y) -> Y;
```

[Erlang strings](http://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/data_types.html#id74716) are list of integers so when your list is not really a string but contains code points of your specified encoding, then it is printed in string notation, but it's still a list. List `[65,65,67,68]` is equal to `"ABCD"`. Try to type that list into your shell, it's just an erlang pretty printing... not accurate sometimes.

Comment: Thanks a lot for that correction, it works well now !
I understand now the relation that Erlang makes between strings and lists.
Very helpfull, thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You probably shouldn't write your own sorting function. If lists:sort(List) isn't what you want for your use case, you could sort on only the first element of the sublists like this:

```
lists:sort(fun ([H1|_],[H2|_]) -> H1 =< H2 end,
           List)
```